# Finding and replacing one column in current sheet on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I found the below code, it works good when "search in sheet".

But sometimes, when I open the excel, it default shows "search worksheet". Please see the image.

Then the code will replace entire sheets instead of Columns("V").

Any additional code can control this thing happens?

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub ReplaceTitleMs()
Columns("V").Replace    What:="Ms ", _
                        Replacement:="", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

[image]

So here is my currently code:

```
Sub Test_Replace()

Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("B").Replace What:="XXX", _
                        Replacement:="KKK", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("B").Replace What:="SIN", _
                        Replacement:="OOO", _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

When select "search in worksheet" in the menu, and run the code.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code is not related to anything shown in the screenshot. And the code would only replace in column V `Columns("V")` but as long as you don't define in which worksheet, Excel guesses. So you might want to specify in which worksheet the column V is: `Worksheets("SheetName").Columns("V").Replace`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I tried put .   Worksheets("SheetName").Columns("V").Replace .  when define "search in sheet", but "search in worksheet" still replace all.

Comment: The documentation [Range.Replace Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-replace-method-excel#examplel) clearly says that for `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace` *The replacement range is column A on Sheet1.* And that is definitely independent from what is selected in that menu. You must be doing something else than running that code. Or the code you showed us is not **exactly** the code you run.

Comment: As I understand, in order to the code running properly, I have to define the  "search in sheet" first in that menu.

Comment: No the code should be completely independent from what you select in that menu. The menu is for manual search only. The code already specifies worksheet and column where the replace should occur. The menu cannot change that code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Please check my code . ' 

Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("B").Replace What:="XXX", _
                            Replacement:="KKK", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

' .         I put same content in different columns, and different sheets, when I select "search in worksheet", and running code, the code replace all the contents. BTW how to post a image in comments?

Comment: Please don't use comments to post code or images (gets unreadable as you see). Instead [edit] your original question to add relevant things and improve your question.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I edited the question

Comment: If this really happens, this must be a bug in Excel Mac (this is against any logic and code would not be reliable): `Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns("B").Replace` clearly defines sheet and column where to replace in. Maybe you find someone with Excel and Mac (I don't have a Mac so I cannot confirm this bug). But this should clearly not happen! What you can try is: Make sure you updated Excel to the latest version (maybe it was fixed already).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, because of I updated to the latest version on Mac, mostly my Marcos doesn't work properly, the find/replace is the biggest issue for me.

Comment: Asking Microsoft for support would be a good idea then